# Understanding the select algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm having trouble understanding how the number of elements in a partitioned set S relate to the kth smallest number. Suppose I have this pseudocode:

```
 Select (k,S)
  if |S|=1 then return a in S
  Choose random a in S
  Let S1,S2,S3 be sets of elements in S (<,=,> to a)
  If |S1|>=k then return Select(k,S1)
  Else if |S1| + |S2| >= k then return a
  Else return Select(k-|S1|-|S2|, S3)
```

From what I know, in order to find the kth smallest element I choose a pivot and sort numbers around the pivot such that all numbers less are to the left and all numbers greater are to the right of the pivot. Then, if I wanted to find the kth smallest number I compare it to the position of the pivot and if the position of the pivot is greater than k I look to the left of the pivot and if the position of the pivot is less than k, I look to the right and recursive from there.

But, in the pseudocode above I don't see where the above comparison with the pivot and k is happening. I mean, shouldn't it compare with a >= k instead of |S1| >= k, since a is the pivot?

How does the number of elements in a set come into play with this comparison with k?

Comment: `Let S1,S2,S3 be sets of elements in S (<,=,> to a)` <-- that's where the first part of the comparison is happening. The rest hinges on `a>b` and `c>b` implies `c>a`. _Maths_ at it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S1 is the set of numbers smaller than a. S2 is the set of the numbers == a. And S3 is the set of number >= a. This already contains lots of comparisons.

Now if |S1| >= k, then the set of numbers smaller than a exceeds k elements. Thus the k smallest number is already contained in S1.

If this is not the case, then it is not contained in S1, thus it must be in S2 or S3.

If |S1|+|S2| >= k, then of course it must be in S1 or S2. Since it is not in S1 it must be in S2. Since S2 = {a} the k smallest number is a.

If none of this is the case then it must be in S3. Thus the search can be constrained to S3. Since the numbers contained in S1 and S2 are missing from S3 and since they are smaller than all numbers in S3 this implies that we have to search for the k-|S1|-|S2| smallest number in S3.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. Good answer and explanation.